# Can't find a codec for class java.lang.Object. while using mongo with scala

Tags: mongodb, scala

I am using mongo with scala.

```
object myApp extends App{

case class myClass(field: String, value: Option[Any])

}
```

Above is my case class and below is the DB code

```
object DB{

  import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries
  import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries._
  import org.mongodb.scala.MongoClient.DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY
  import org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.Macros._
  import org.mongodb.scala.{MongoClient, MongoCollection, MongoDatabase}

  private val codecs = fromProviders(classOf[myClass])

  private val codecReg = fromRegistries(codecs,
    DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY)

  private val dataB:  MongoDatabase = MongoClient().getDatabase("database").withCodecRegistry(codecReg)

  val myClass: MongoCollection[Rule] = dataB.getCollection("myClass")

}
```

now, the "value" can have String/Int/None value. If I define a myClass with value as 'None' i.e

```
val c = myClass("abc", None)
```

and put this in database than it runs without ant error, but if i keep value as Some(String_value) or Some(int_value) than it shows the error.

```
val d = myClass("abc", Some("xyz"))
val f = myClass("abc", Some(90))
```

error

```
Can't find a codec for class java.lang.Object
```

Can somebody guide me how should I do this as "value" field can have String/Int/None values.

Comment: `Any` means anything, there is no way that **mongo** could create a codec for that. If you know it will be either an `Int` or a `String` then you can use an `Option[Either[String, Int]]` or create your own **ADT**.

Comment: Thank you for helping. if I use ```case class myClass(field: String, value:Option[Either[String, Int]])``` than how to create instances

Comment: Like this? `MyClass("abc", Some(Right("xyz")))` Not sure what was the question. - Also, not sure if **mongo** supports `Either`, maybe not; but it probably does support a custom **ADT** so you can do something like [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/uFEW1vGKT7qwiPM6XJMPdQ).

Comment: As I tried ```val c = myClass("abc", Some(Left("xyz")))``` but it throws error
```Can't find a codec for class scala.util.Left.```

Comment: Yeah that is what I mean with that probably **Mongo** wouldn't support `Either` , cam you try with the **ADT** approach I also shared? Take a look to [this](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver-scala/bson/macros/#sealed-classes-and-adts), remember to als register `MyCustomType`.